# js получить значение из hash ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите как получить из ссылки значение
Ссылка такого вида : http://mysite.ru/link?variant_id=196388417

Как на экран мне показать значение '196388417', которое назначено в ссылке ?variant_id=

Помогите кодом, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может так

```js
// document.location
const document_location = 'http://mysite.ru/link?variant_id=196388417'
const variant_id = document_location.replace(/.*\?/, '')
  .split('&')
  .map((pv) => pv.split('='))
  .find(([p]) => p === 'variant_id')

console.log(
  variant_id ? variant_id[1] : undefined
)
```

Comment: как вывести на экран

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript умеет парсить URL'ы. API так и называется: [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL). Безобразие с ручным парсингом пора прекращать.

```js
let id = new URL("http://mysite.ru/link?variant_id=196388417")
    .searchParams.get('variant_id');
console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не самое красивое решение.

```js
const string = 'http://mysite.ru/link?variant_id=196388417';
const result = string.slice(string.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: как вывести на экран

Comment: document.body.textContent = result

Answer (score 0):

```
const str = 'http://mysite.ru/link?variant_id=196388417';
const result = str.slice(str.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, что без подсветки, писал с телефона)